# Artisan error doesn't show line number

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I'm writing a console command for my Laravel 5.1 app. While developing, I'm having an error somewhere. When artisan reports the error, it doesn't give me the line number or file; I just get an error in the shell highlighted in red background:

```
  [ErrorException]
  Undefined variable: answerer
```

How do I get artisan to show me more information about where the error occurred, specifically line number and file?

Comment: can you tell me getting this error is which artisan command ?

Comment: I wrote a custom command called `survey:complete`.

Comment: Ok, may be error on your custom command code.
search answerer variable on command action code

Comment: @DipeshShihora It is an error in my custom code. I want artisan to report the file and line number to ease the searching.

Comment: Try this solution https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-command-not-showing-any-errors

Answer (score 17):

Since this is the first hit in Google for me, I reply here. I managed to find a solution to this issue. Simply add the -v option to artisan for getting a stacktrace, including line number.

```
php artisan -v survey:complete
```

in your case.

Comment: i get the error In Application.php line 592:
                                                                    
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\NamespaceNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "survey" namespace.

Comment: That is because survey:complete is a custom command from the opening post. You have to use `php artisan -v [insert your command here]`. The `-v` is the solution here.